# Making positive charged polyacrylamide

Tags: biochemistry, lab-techniques, gel-electrophoresis

I am interested in positive charged polyacrylamide to electrophorese molecules I am interested in.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2643323/
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bip.360300309/pdf

The articles shown above use allyltriethylammonium bromide (ATAB), but I am not sure which chemical they mention.

Or is there any other chemical to add to acrylamide to get positive charged polyacrylamide copolymer?

Comment: I would say that this question is better suited for chemistry.se.

Answer (score 1):

[ATAB](http://www.scbt.com/sv/datasheet-278687-allyltriethylammonium-bromide.html) contains a quaternary amine and a terminal carbon-carbon double bond. The polyacrylamide reaction links [acrylamide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylamide) by their double bonds forming the polymer. The double bond on ATAB can be incorporated into the growing polymer chain, and the quaternary amine holds a positive charge, making a positively charged polymer.

The [immobilines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immobilized_pH_gradient) mentioned are probably just a weak acid or weak base group with a terminal double bond like ATAB or acrlyamide. They get trapped into the polymer and if you pour the gel with a pH gradient, they pick up charges according to the pH. I haven't found a good concrete immobiline example, I can't access that second article you linked.

I am away from my good computer and cannot make chemical structures right now.

Comment: Thank you. I sensed how it works when I read, but I was not able to find the commercial products so I was wondering why. Now I find it.